# Multiple Lock Objects in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

here is my code

```
private String tableName1 = "Customers_Home";
private String tableName2 = "Customers_Work";
private String tableName3 = "Customers_Away";

public void insertData(List<Object> data1, List<Object> data2, List<Object> data3) {
   //inserts data into back-end database
   insertTable1Data(tableName1, data1);
   insertTable2Data(tableName2, data2);
   insertTable3Data(tableName3, data3);
   //there are more insertTableData() calls.
}

public List<List<Object>> getData() {

   //select data from back-end database
   List<Object> table1Data = getTable1Data(tableName1);
   List<Object> table2Data = getTable2Data(tableName2);
   List<Object> table3Data = getTable3Data(tableName3);

List<List<Object>> tableData = new ArrayList<>();
tableData.addAll(table1Data);
tableData.addAll(table2Data);
tableData.addAll(table3Data);
return tableData;
}
```

Problem: 
getData() is sometimes returning empty list or incomplete values, possible cause insertData() hasn't finished before getData() is called, a threading issue, so what i did, used Lock in insertData() and getData() as

```
public void insertData(List<Object> data1, List<Object> data2, List<Object> data3) {
       //inserts data into back-end database
ReadWriteLock lock1 = getLock(tableName1);//returns a ReadWriteLock from HashMap based on tableName (key).
     boolean acquired = false;
      do {
           acquired = lock1.writeLock().tryLock(5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
         } while (!acquired);
       insertTable1Data(tableName1, data1);

       ReadWriteLock lock2 = getLock(tableName2);
       acquired = false;
       do {
           acquired = lock2.writeLock().tryLock(5, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
         } while (!acquired);
       insertTable2Data(tableName2, data2);
       //and a similar do while block for tableName3.
       insertTable3Data(tableName3, data3);
       //Ommitted try, catch, finally block and unlocking operation.
    }
```

This approach is creating a Lock Object for each insertTableData() operation, but I want to use only one Lock object for each insertData() operation, how to achieve that ?

Any suggestions ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make it a field variable so you can reference it again after the method has completed, instead of creating a new one each time the method is called

Comment: Why are you trying to lock every 5 milliseconds? Can you not just run the `lock()` method which actually blocks until lock is held? Also, can you elaborate on what you mean by it creating a new object every time? Are the tables ever accessed separately? Can you just not share a single lock over the period where tables are accessed?